# Updating column values of a table with column values from a different table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table (`Table 1`) with columns `FN`, `LN`, `MN` and eleven other columns. I have another table (`Table 2`) which has `FN`, `LN`, `MN` (only three columns).

I want to update my values `FN`, `LN` and `MN` in the `Table 1` with the values `FN`, `LN` and `MN` from `Table 2`.

I do NOT need to Join on the basis of any other common column.

Please let me know if there is a way to do it.

I cannot use a `SELECT * INTO` statement because the structure of the two tables is not the same. `Table 1` has 11 odd columns and `Table 2` has 3 columns.

Comment: Can you provide a sample data of Table 1 and table 2 and your desired result. May be just 3 rows each.

Comment: Table 1 has : ID   FirstName  MiddleName   LastName     -----other columns---                                                        Table 2 has : FirstName    MiddleName    LastName                         What I want is All the table2 values should be populate to Table1 with all the other column values of Table1 remaining the same.

Answer (score 1):

If `Table 1` contains:

```
[FN]           [LN]     [MN]    [A]          [B]     [C]
--------------------------------------------------------
hello          world     123    something    else    456
other          row        45    demo         data    789
something      else      456    NULL         NULL    999
```

and `Table 2` contains:

```
[FN]           [LN]     [MN]
----------------------------
table          two         1
just-a-demo    here        2
final          row         3
```

and the expected result is:

```
[FN]           [LN]     [MN]    [A]          [B]     [C]
--------------------------------------------------------
table          two         1    something    else    456
just-a-demo    here        2    demo         data    789
final          row         3    NULL         NULL    999
```

you can first get the expected result like this;

```
select [S].[FN], [S].[LN], [S].[MN], [F].[A], [F].[B], [F].[C] from
(
    select top 10
        row_number() over (order by (select 1)) as [Id], [A], [B], [C]
    from [Table 1]
) as [F]
left join
(
    select top 10
        row_number() over (order by (select 1)) as [Id], [FN], [LN], [MN]
    from [Table 2]
) as [S]
on [F].[Id] = [S].[Id]
```

Note:

- The `top 10`: you may need to remove this, but you must be sure both tables return the same number of rows. If they don't, there is no way to do 1:1 mapping according to the information you gave in the comments.
- `row_number() over (order by (select 1))` simply puts "1" for the first returned row, "2" for the next one, etc. This is a weird way to join the results from two tables: I would expect to have an actual ID in both tables, or something which enables to do an actual join.

You can then insert it into a temporary table:

what you can do is to use the `insert into` with a subquery `select` like this:

```
insert into [TempTable] ([FN], [LN], [MN], [A], [B], [C])
    select [S].[FN], [S].[LN], [S].[MN], [F].[A], [F].[B], [F].[C] from
    (
        select top 10
            row_number() over (order by (select 1)) as [Id], [A], [B], [C]
        from [Table 1]
    ) as [F]
    left join
    (
        select top 10
            row_number() over (order by (select 1)) as [Id], [FN], [LN], [MN]
        from [Table 2]
    ) as [S]
    on [F].[Id] = [S].[Id]
```

and then replace `[Table 1]` by `[TempTable]`.

Comment: hey, the other column does not allow null values. When i try to execute the above it says "Cannot insert null into other columns", so I want the data in other columns to remain as it is. Any other way I can proceed?

Comment: What do you mean by "to remain as it is"? If you're inserting rows, there is no prior data. If you're updating existent rows, then you should specify how the match between two tables should be done.

Comment: Basically I need to update data only the three columns with other columns values remaining the same. Let me know if you understood, otherwise i could explain in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the way that you are looking for.

```
Declare @table1 Table
    (id int identity(1,1), 
    FN varchar(15), 
    LN varchar(15), 
    MN varchar(15),
    Flag1 int default(1),
    Flag2 int default(1),
    Flag3 int default(0))

Declare @table2 Table
    (id int identity(1,1), FN varchar(15), LN varchar(15), MN varchar(15))

Insert into @table1 (Fn,LN,MN) Values 
('A','B','C'),('A','B','D'),('A','X','C')
Insert into @table2 (Fn,LN,MN) Values 
('A','B','C'),('A','B','D'),('A','Y','C')
```

[image]

```
Merge into @table1 A
using @table2 B On 
        A.FN = B.FN AND
        A.LN = B.LN AND
        A.MN = B.MN
When Not Matched then
Insert (FN,LN,MN)
Values (B.FN,B.LN,B.MN); 

Select * from @table1
```

**Result**

[image]